# change the value of a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to change the value of a drop down list using the following code on the  `click` event handler. Nothing actually changes when the button is pressed. What am I missing? Is this the correct way to do this?

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement salutation = document.GetElementById("status");
salutation.SetAttribute("value", "Mr");
```

Here is the html

```
<select id="status">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, a `<select>` has multiple `<option>` values.  So, no, not likely this code is correct.  It isn't clear what element "status" might be but reasonable odds that you'll need at least salutation.FirstChild.

Comment: @Hans Passant that's the id of the select element i added the html to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (based on your code)

```
      HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement salutation = document.GetElementById("status");

        var option = salutation.Children.Cast<HtmlElement>().First(x => x.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Mr"));
        option.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: @Mr.1.0 this worked for using your code. How are you loading the html? from a url or from a string?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 Can you show more of your code? where are you setting the html? and notice that i've modified my code a bit.

Comment: i'm setting the webbrowser url from the the form.cs tab

Comment: i'm able to add text to input fine. just the options i have an issue with.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 Use my answer as it is. I'm pretty sure you are missing something. I created a new project just to try this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you selecting the `<select>` tag? If so, don't use that. Select the `<option>`, just like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

To see it in action: See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jQnxM/)

#### Using some codes from scartag, how about this:

```
HtmlElement salutation = document.GetElementById("status");

var option = salutation.Children.Cast<HtmlElement>().
             Where(x => x.GetAttribute("selected").Equals("selected")).First();

if (option != null) option.SetAttribute("value","Mr,");
```

Comment: @Freddie Fabregas dont i have to call the select to get to the option?